# Matlab Isolating 2D Array from 3D Matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D matrix called M of size <100x100x100>, so basically  coordinates.

I am trying to get the array of  at specific values of y. However using M(:,1,:) I get a <100x1x100> matrix whereas finding  I can use M(:,:,1) and get a <100x100> matrix.

Is there an easy way to turn the <100x1x100> into a <100x100> by either isolating it a different way or using a short translation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does `squeeze` do what you want?

```
a = ones(100, 1, 100);
b = squeeze(a);
size(b) % 100x100
```

Comment: `squeeze` removes ALL singleton dimensions from the n-D matrix, even those that are not intended specifically to be singleton. Not ideal.